# Expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement some webcam jquery script / plugin into my page, in firefox it works flawlessly, in IE i'm getting this error:

Expected identifier, string or number.
Line 151
Char 13

Which is the following part:

```
        $.webcam._flash = $("#jquerywebcamflash");
    }
    else
    {
        $.webcam._flashready = true;
    }

    $.webcam._flash.flash(
        {
            src: 'jquerywebcamhelper.swf',
            width: $.webcam._width,
            height: $.webcam._height,
        },
        {
            version: 8
        }
    );
}
```

Line 151 char 13 would be this one: `},`

the complete .js can be found here: [jquery.webcam.js pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/7Uq1pWpZ)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must remove comma from this line:

`height: $.webcam._height,`

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'll accept as soon as i can. Could you have a look at this: Line 179 Char 13 : Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Please create another question with jsfiddler working example. I think your problem lies in those two lines:             $(document).find("body").append($(canvas));
            $.webcam._canvas = $('#jquerywebcamcanvas'); but am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the trailing comma:

```
$.webcam._flash.flash(
    {
        src: 'jquerywebcamhelper.swf',
        width: $.webcam._width,
        height: $.webcam._height
    },
    {
        version: 8
    }
);
```

IE doesn't like the extraneous comma in object declarations.